# 2-d array in c++

Tags: c++

```
vector< vector<int> > vI2Matrix(3, vector<int>(2,0));
```

I know it  declares size of two dimensional array and initializes it. But waht does (2,0 ) means?
is there any necessary to put it here?
thanks

When I delete (2,0) or change it to other value. The compilation is right but I got runtime segmentation fault after that.

Comment: If you are getting segmentation fault means, definitely you are not accessing the element that belong to the vector. (i.e., `vI2Matrix` is a 3*2 matrix in this case )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vector<int>(2,0)` initializes the vector with two elements with the value of 0.